# 3D stackbar on map in QGIS

Tags: qgis

[image]This is a stack bar plot made by QGIS 3.18 (2nd image). All I want is to flip the image and overlap this plot as 3D in QGIS (Like image 1st). How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Is this a layout that you can modify in QGIS or just an image. What kind of flip, horizontal, vertical or just rotation?

Comment: He want to see 3D view and bar plot on maps, but I think that you @kazi must have 3D terrain?

Comment: Yes I want flat 3D view with no terrain.